# Unable to retrieve the public ip address of the fargate containers created using jenkins build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs

Can anyone please help me with the command to retrieve the public ip address of the ecs fargate containers created using jenkins CI/CD pipeline.

(need to display the public ip address in the jenkins build console output as the testers are not having access to aws console for checking the newly deployed services in aws ecs cluster using service and taskdefinition)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the task ID (e.g. ceebc8d37409490693478ad5f2fbff93), you should be able to grab the ENI ID associated to the Fargate task and then you could query the public IP associated to the ENI:

```
export TASK=ceebc8d37409490693478ad5f2fbff93 

ENI_ID=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --task $TASK | jq -r '.tasks[].attachments[].details[] | select(.name=="networkInterfaceId") | .value')

ENI_PUBLIC_IP=$(aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces | jq -r ".NetworkInterfaces[] | select(.NetworkInterfaceId==\"$ENI_ID\") | .Association.PublicIp") 

echo $ENI_PUBLIC_IP
```